# Can you pass a temporary object to a function that takes a variable by reference?

Tags: c++

I am having a problem understanding a compiler error.

The member function `add()` being called on an object named `rolo` takes a `Card` variable by reference:

```
class Card{
public:
    Card(string first,string last,string occupation,string address,string phoneNum);
};

class Rolodex{
public:
    void add(Card& card);
};

int main()
{
    Rolodex rolo;
    rolo.add(Card("Tony", "Hansen", "Writer", "12 E. St. NY, NY 33333", "555-9999"));
}
```

The compiler is giving me an error on this line:

```
rolo.add(Card("Tony", "Hansen", "Writer", "12 E. St. NY, NY 33333", "555-9999"));
```

> Non-const lvalue reference to type 'Card' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Card'.

I don't think that it is legal to call the method with a temporary object as argument. 
I think it is better if the following is done instead:

```
Card variable("Tony", "Hansen", "Writer", "12 E. St. NY, NY 33333", "555-9999");
rolo.add(variable);
```

Why is the error happening? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your title to use proper capitalization. If you write in all capital letters, people will think you are shouting at them.

Comment: If you replace "copy constructor" with "a temporary" everywhere in your question, it begins to make sense...

Comment: `variable = new Card...` is an error. This isn't Java

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind a temporary to a **non-const lvalue reference** (`Card& card`). One solution is to pass it as a **const lvalue reference** instead:

```
void add(Card const & card);
```

Comment: Actually, you *can* bind a temporary to a non-`const` reference - just not to a non-`const` *lvalue* reference. You can bind a temporary to a non-`const` rvalue reference, like `Card&&`.

Comment: @H.G: the C++98 standard is superseded since more than a decade (although the superseding C++03 also doesn't have rvalue references). The current active standard is C++14 which superseded the C++11 standard introducing rvalue references, i.e., rvalue references are part of the C++ standard since about half a decade. I don't see any reason to discuss historic C++ rules. I *do* realize, however, that this fine distinction may be lost on the person asking the original question...

Comment: @user3558677: the way to indicate that you got your question answered in a satisfying way is to *accept* it! You may also want to upvote the answer if you think it is helpful.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I totally agree .. I just wanted to have a generic answer since the c++ version is not added to the question .. Otherwise, sad fact, many organizations are stuck with c++98, and they can't really upgrade for various reasons. So, it's not history yet :)  ... I updated my answer to clarify this point .. thanks for your comment !

Comment: I don't see the option for accept. Im new to this, sorry.